# Solow model with three input factors

Tags: production-function, solow, cobb-douglas

My problem is that I want to construct a Solow model with three input factors; labour, capital and energy. But when trying to divid the equation by labour to get the per capita variables, it doesn’t work link in the model with two inputs.

My equation is:

Y = K^α * L^β * E^γ

I don’t know how I can get the per capita variables by dividing by L.

I also haven’t found anything on the web, so I hope the someone could help me with this little problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the production function you specified you won’t get ‘clean’ per capita production function.

However, to get it in per capita terms you just literally have to divide both sides of equation by $L$ and that’s it.

In your case per capita output is:

$$\frac{Y}{L} =\frac{ K^α  L^{\beta}  E^γ }{L} $$

Which simplifies to:

$$\frac{Y}{L} = K^αL^{β-1}  E^γ $$

If you want some nicer equation use Cobb-Douglas production function. That is set $\beta = 1-\alpha - γ  $ and assume $\alpha, γ >0$. Then you will get nice per capita output equation:

$$\frac{Y}{L} = \frac{ K^α  L^{1-\alpha - γ}  E^γ }{L}$$

This can be rearranged as:

$$\frac{Y}{L} = \frac{ K^α   E^γ }{L^\alpha L^ γ }$$

Which simplifies to:

$$\frac{Y}{L} = \left(\frac{ K}{L}\right)^α  \left(\frac{ E}{L}\right)^γ $$

Then you can use lower case to denote per capita variables to get ‘nice’ per capita production function:

$$y= \left(k\right)^α  \left(e\right)^γ $$

Comment: Thank you very much! This seem so  obvious now. 

I think in the exponent of L in your first equation there should only be the beta and not the (beta - 1)

Comment: @EliasChrostian no it’s beta- 1 because L^beta / L = L^beta -1